# How to add a field in database table by cakephp migration?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am very new in cakephp version 3. Here I am trying to use migration plugin. I have already created a table by using below command

```
=> cake bake migration CreateUsers name : string
```

It's worked very fine, now I am trying to add a field in here so I have written

```
=> cake bake migration add age:int to Users
```

It's not working. How can I add this field by migration using shall command ?May you help me please ?

Comment: Even if it might be obvious for people who are used to the migrations plugin, "_doesn't work_" is _never_ a proper problem description! Please always be specific as to what exactly happens, and what you expect to happen instead!

Comment: It's create a file with a method 
public function change()
 {
 }

But it's totally blank.

Comment: .I am actually trying to add a new field in users table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A syntax like

```
add column:type to table
```

doesn't exist, so that's why you are seeing what you're seeing. The correct syntax for adding columns is

```
AddColumnNameToTableName column:type
```

where the column name between `Add` and `To` is optional.

ie your command should look something like

```
bin/cake bake migration AddAgeToUsers age:int
```

See

- **[Cookbook > Migrations > Creating Migrations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html#creating-migrations)**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/migrations**

Comment: Of course, I kinda implied that people would do that, I didn't ment to promote bad practice :) Let me edit my answer...

Comment: I don't think it counts as a bad practice, rather a bad habit by doc writes (myself included) which persists - in any case thanks for correcting the answer (and I assume: future answers =)) - good work.