# Migration in cakephp3

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-migration, phinx

I am new to cakephp3.refer http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html and try to create database using terminal.for example:

```
bin/cake bake migration CreateProducts name:string description:text created modified
```

this command create file and when use below command it creates database table in phpmyadmin:

```
bin/cake migrations migrate
```

But I want to update table with add one column in it..so when I try to update database table it create another migration file ..each time when I want to update database table..these seems weired..because I want to update single table..
Is there any way ,so I am updating database table with same function each time through migration??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using migration,see in database there has a table name `phinxlog`. In this table there has a field name called `version`. When you will give command

```
bin/cake migrations migrate
```

Then this table will be update. Now see the version field, here some number like `20150911090111`. This number actually added with your migration file, am I right ?

If this number already accessed in your `phinxlog` table, this file will never access again. That means after your command

```
 bin/cake migrations migrate
```

That command will not apply on this file which already accessed in `pinixlog` table.

So don't be afraid if another migration file has been created.
For add new column please see

[How to add a field in database table by cakephp migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628874/how-to-add-a-field-in-database-table-by-cakephp-migration)

Yes, It's also possible to add new column in your old migration file, just add manually like

```
->addColumn('field_name', 'types', [
                'default' => null,
                'limit' => 11,
                'null' => false,
 ])
```

Then rename the file name. Then give the `migration migrate` again.I hope it will work now.

Comment: ok..now my doubt clear..thanks for help..IS it possible to migrate all data along with column name using:bin/cake bake migration_snapshot Initial   ??

Comment: Yes it's possible. After add new column if all column has been added then apply 
bin/cake bake migration_snapshot Initial command again. Make sure new Initial migration file position on top. You can do it by rename file. I think you know about the meaning of 20150911090111 this digits meaning.

Comment: bin/cake bake migration_snapshot Initial command migrate only database tables and its columns ,but i want to also migrate all tables rows/Data ...so is it possible??

Comment: ok I understand, No it's not possible but you can make your own dummy data insert code. 
see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712896/cakephp-how-to-use-migration-to-insert-records

You have to add it manually.